# Does using a Jagged dagger, used as an implement, get the ongoing 10 damage for attacks

Tags: dnd-4e

Does using a Jagged dagger, used as an implement, get the ongoing 10 damage for attacks, or is it just "weapon" attacks?

> **Jagged Weapon**
>
>   Weapon: Axe, heavy blade or light blade
>   Enhancement Bonus: attack rolls and damage rolls
>   Critical: Ongoing 10 damage (save ends)
>       Level 22 and 27: Ongoing 20 damage (save ends)
>   Property
>   This weapon scores critical hits on a 19 or 20.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

It does not specify the *types* of attacks that it can be used on, so it's *all* attacks channeled through the dagger. The type of wording that would limit this would be "This weapon scores a critical hit on a 19 or 20 when used for weapon attacks" or similar.

Comment: In addition to Wax Eagle's correct answer (this would be a comment if i had 50 rep!), it's worth noting that weapons/implements with status effects on a crit instead of bonus damage are the only crit effects that still apply if you crit using an attack that does not deal damage.